# How to set bounds for spinal line with axisartist?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I set the bounds of `axisartist.axis[].line`?

With the normal API, its possible to set bounds of the axis spine with:

```
ax.spines['right'].set_bounds(low=0.01,high=0.1)
```

But `axisartist` does not have a `spines` object. Instead, spinal lines are implemented with `ax.axis['left'].line`, which does not have a `get_bounds` and `set_bounds` method.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as axisartist
import seaborn as sns

use_artist = True

x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)

x.sort()
y.sort()

if use_artist:
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(axes_class=axisartist.Axes)
else:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
ax.scatter(x, y, marker="o")

if use_artist:
    ax.axis['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.axis['top'].set_visible(False)
    
    # HOW TO SET BOUNDS OF ax.axis['left'].line here?
    
else:
    sns.despine()
    ax.spines['left'].set_bounds(ax.get_yticks()[1], ax.get_yticks()[-2])
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_bounds(ax.get_xticks()[1], ax.get_xticks()[-2])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Here are examples without and with `axisartist`:

[image: Example with normal API]
[image: Example with axisartist]

Answer (score 0):

Use `axes.set_xbounds()` or `axes.set_xlim()` (docs found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xbound.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-xbound) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-xlim) respectively). Both methods appear identical in function, but `set_xlim` has more functionality, should you require it. So your new modified code using only `axisartist` is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as axisartist

# Data
x = np.random.random(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
x.sort()
y.sort()

# Creating figure, plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(axes_class=axisartist.Axes)
ax.scatter(x, y, marker="o")

# Formatting axes
ax.axis['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.axis['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.axis['left'].major_ticklabels.set_pad(10)
ax.axis['bottom'].major_ticklabels.set_pad(10)

# Setting axis limits
ax.set_xlim(left=0.2, right = 0.5)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top = 0.7)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I want the plot to have y and x limits that defer from the bounds of the line, so the entire axes line is not shown, but only a part of it, "ax.set_ylim()" set the limits of the axes, but i want the line of the spine to be only drawn for a part of the axes

Comment: Ah apologies, I slightly misunderstood your exact question. In that case, I don't believe you are able to do so using `axisartist`. I'll edit my answer appropriately